# How to remove one billion files from single directory on linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, debian

I'm trying to remove about one billion files located in a single directory under linux with this command:

```
# rm /test/*.mp3
```

but execution is fault with this message:

```
-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Avoid having a big lot of files in a single flat directory. Use sub-directories like `/test/d1/f0001.mp3` ... `/test/d99/f9901.mp3`

Comment: ...And not just because it causes problems like this. Many filesystems perform poorly with more than tens of thousands of files per directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I frequently use something of the form

```
find /test/ -name '*.mp3' -delete
```

This allows each file to be processed in turn, rather than a glob trying to list all the files as arguments to the rm command.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` is usually smart about generating reasonable-sized argument lists; try

```
ls -1 /test/*.mp3 | xargs rm
```

This batches the arguments together, but avoids creating command invocations that are too long to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I am on iPad but use Linux a lot)

From /, execute

```
# rm -rf test
```

Comment: i don't need delete directory, only files inside

Answer (score 1):

Another Pop Favorite is "`find temp -name "*.mp3" -exec rm {} \;`"

Comment: Yes, you have to use the `-exec` for instead of `-delete` if your system is more than about 5 years old, or isn't using GNU `find`. `-delete` is a relatively recent invention, and it doesn't exist in other `find` implementations.